# Nginx configuration for static files

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js

I need an advice, how to solve this:

I have two websites example1.com and example2.com
They both made on NuxtJS and works well.

For them I am using Nginx.

I need to do this:
If I going to address example2.com/custompage I need to show page and static files from example1.com/custompage *(I am not need redirect on this page, I need to show this page exactly on example2.com/custompage)*, but when I going to any other page of example2.com I need to keep all pages and files from example2.com

Is it possible to do this with Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `proxy_pass`. First, run NuxtJS apps in two ports like `3000` and `3001` then use proxy pass and upstream to do that

```
upstream nuxt1 {
    server localhost:3000;
}

upstream nuxt2 {
    server localhost:3001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example2.com

    location /custompage/ {
        proxy_pass http://nuxt1/custompage/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nuxt2;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. This works but on a half. Text from custompage I get, but assets are 404 error - _nuxt/a3gffs33.js .....etc, images are also 404 error, because on nuxt1 there are no full addresses to this assets, they are like "/images/image.jpeg" and all static files are 404

Answer (score 0):

After following the steps mentioned above.

In your Nuxt Project(nuxt1), you need to add the following to your nuxt.config.js file,

```
router : {
  base: "/custompage/"
}
```

Also, note if you are using any files from the `Static` folder, example an image , example.png.

You have to use them like

```
<v-img src="example.png" />
```

And `NOT`,

```
<v-img src="/example.png" />
```

If you are using dynamic variable, add an variable in .env , for the router.base

```
<v-img :src="ENV_VAR + dynamic_variable" />
```